# Is it possible to create an apk file before deploying php mobile application in server?

Tags: php

To creata apk file for php mobile application.
is it necessary to deploy it in the server before creating apk?

Comment: please explain, PHP mobile application?

Comment: It's just a mobile application developed using PHP software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible,

Enter address as `http://ip-address/` followed by the path of your PHP file in your code.

> For example http://192.168.1.7/test/example.php

You could get your IP address By executing `ifconfig` in the terminal

To test your app for Android localhost connection with PHP MySQL in Android Mobile Phone, your computer and mobile phone should be connected to the **same Wi-Fi router**.

***Note:*** Before putting your address into the code, test address in your mobile browser for whether the address is accessible or not.